# Why is it that $A^{-1} = (I-N)^{-1} = I + N + N^2 + N^3$ in this case

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-explanation

I am looking at this solution to this problem. The Gaussian elimination part is easy, but I don't quite follow the second part.

Why is it that $A^{-1} = (I-N)^{-1} = I + N + N^2 + N^3$, and how do we easily tell that $N^4 = 0$?

[image]

Comment: "and how do we easily tell that $N^4 = 0$?" Because $N$ is a nilpotent $4\times 4$-matrix. Recall that a nilpotent matrix $A$ of size $n$ satisfies $A^n=0$ (characteristic polynomial). The other part is the geometric series, which becomes zero for all powers $N^k$ with $k\ge 4$, again because $N^4=0$.

Comment: If $e_i$ are the vectors with zeros everywhere except for a $1$ in the $i$-th position, then $Ne_4=0$, $Ne_3=-ce_4$, $Ne_2=-be_3$ and $Ne_1=-ae_2$. So, $N^4e_i=0$ for all $i$. Note that for any matrix $B$, $Be_i$ is the $i$-th column of $B$. Then all columns of $N^4$ are zero. To check that $(I-N)^4=I+N+N^2+N^3$ you can multiply $(I-N)(I+N+N^2+N^3)=I+N+N^2+N^3-N-N^2-N^3-N^4=I-N^4=I$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde "$N^4=0$ because $N$ is nilpotent..." is a circular argument.

Comment: @Urtur The matrix $N$ is nilpotent, because it is strictly upper-triangular. But then why should we have $N^4=0$? This is what I mean.  I wrote "$N^4=0$, because $N$ is a nilpotent $4\times 4$ matrix" (and not of size $5$, say). So it is not circular.

Comment: @DietrichBurde "because it is strictly upper-triangular" is something that you are adding now and still not a proof either. So, yes, your first comment is still circular.

Comment: @Urtur No, it is not circular. Of course one can give more details for a proof, but my statement is just that it is obvious that $N$ is nilpotent and hence  $N^4=0$ since it has size $4$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde And my comment is that the OP shouldn't use your comment as an argument since it is circular and doesn't prove anything. That's all.

Comment: Again, it is not circular. You want to interpret it as such. Of course, the OP should rather look for a proof why $N$ is nilpotent. But it is obvious, being an upper-triangular matrix (see the answer below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If $A$ is a strictly upper triangular matrix of size $n \times n$, then $A^n = O$.
   To prove this, try inductively showing that with each power of $A$, the "upper diagonals successively become $0$".
2. Now, suppose that $A = I - N$, where all the matrices written are square. (Here, $A$ and $N$ are general $n \times n$ matrices, nothing to do with the question.)
   Fix $k \geqslant 2$ and expand $$A(I + N + \cdots + N^{k - 1}) = (I - N)(I + \cdots + N^{k - 1})$$
   to see that you get $I - N^k$. (The above is simply using the identity $$x^n - 1 = (x - 1)(x^{n - 1} + \cdots + 1),$$
   which holds because $I$ and $N$ commute.)
   In particular, if $N^k = O$, then $$A(I + N + \cdots + N^{k - 1}) = I - N^k = I.$$ ($k = n$ is not required.)

---

Aside: As a heuristic, you can see that this is mimicking the following identity:

$$\frac{1}{1 - x} = 1 + x + x^2 + \cdots.$$

Of course, one must be careful how one interprets the above. The above is true *analytically* for $x \in \Bbb C$ satisfying $|x| < 1$.

On the other hand, it can also be interpreted *algebraically* as equality in the ring of formal power series. (That is, $(1 - x)(1 + x + x^2 + \cdots) = 1$.)

In our case, we see that the infinite sum $I + N + N^2 + \cdots$ is actually a finite sum and the second perspective helps us in concluding that $(I - N)(I + N + \cdots + N^{k - 1}) = I$.)